# Query to get users with highest number of sites with at least one famous question

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer, views

I want to know who are the top users across all sites in terms of **number of sites** in which they've got at least one famous question (so, count is across sites, not across famous questions).

I know nothing of SQL and have been essentially trying to copy/paste other queries to my needs. Have invested lots of time now and decided to ask here instead. My last attempt:

```
SELECT userId AS [User Link],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Name IN ('Famous Question') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Famous"
  FROM sys.databases 
  INNER JOIN Badges AS b
    ON b.UserId = userId
  WHERE b.Name = 'Famous Question'
  ORDER BY "Famous" DESC
```

Code doesn't work, nor do I know how to correct it. No surprises there since I know nothing of SQL. Could someone help out please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I wrote [such a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/748298/holders-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide?badgename=Famous+Question) four years ago. @rene and others taught me how to write cross-site database queries, which admittedly takes some advanced SQL skills, and this was one of my first ones.

[image]

Since you're new to SQL, I can highly recommend the [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by @MonicaCellio.